# How do I change default Modal hotkey Shift+O to Shift+Q in Blender?

Tags: shortcut, proportional-editing

[image]E.g.: When I am moving vertex points with proportional editing on, in order to cycle through different proportional falloff I want to assign modal hotkey as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.
Default <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> is very inconvenient and i need to use it very often.

To understand better try this in Blender:

1. Take a grid plane. Go to edit mode. Turn on Proportional editing with hotkey 'O'.
2. Now select any middle vertex/face and press 'G' and then 'Z' to move it in z axis
3. Now when you press 'Shift+O' you can change the proportional editing falloffs types. This is exactly where I want to use 'Shift+Q' hotkey instead of 'Shift+O'

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

Go to <kbd>Edit</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Keymap</kbd>. Select <kbd>Key Binding</kbd> and type <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> into the search field. Ths will show all the places where that hotkey combination is used in Blender and you can click on the relevent ones and insert your own preference. Then hit the bottom-left icon and <kbd>Save Preferences</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: I am aware of this method of changing hotkey. Unfortunately modal keys do not show up in this. Please check edited question for extra explanation.

Comment: That works for me! Shift-Q now brings up the proportional falloff pie menu instead of Shift-O which I assume is what you wanted?

Comment: I am not talking about pie menu. When you are moving with G key, without confirming the action press Shift+O to change the falloff. Note that this is modal function key. You are still in the move state. 
The state of cycling through falloff shows up in the upper left corner.

Comment: Ah ok. That's clear now you've uppdated your question. I doubt it's possible while you're already in the process of moving something.